# why panel.webview.asWebviewUri is null

Tags: visual-studio-code

when I print panel.webview.asWebviewUri, I found it is null
`console.log(panel.webview.asWebviewUri);`

I want to use panel.webview.asWebviewUri normally

Comment: where are you printing this? The VS Code devtools console?